# If statement in jQuery plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I have a jQuery plugin with an if statement in it.

For some strange reason (probably it is just me screwing things up) it always gets in the `else` part even when the url's are the same.

```
if (opts.startUrl == track.permalink.url) {
  var active = true;
} else {
  alert('|'+opts.startUrl+'| |'+track.permalink_url+'|');
  var active = false;
}
```

Check it out @ http://dev.upcoming-djs.com

Comment: I would print out what startUrl and permalink.url are e.g. by using console.log.  Make sure they are genuinely identical and no trailing or leading space.  Not sure if type-coercion is at play here - you might want to look at using ===

Comment: @planetjones +1, I was thinking === too.  The url's look similar from his sample.  The other option would be to use .toString() on each piece.

Comment: @planetjones: They are also the same using console.log (check it out I've uploaded it to the server). Why do I need to look at ===? If == fails === would definitely fail.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The surrounding code uses `track.permalink_url`, while the `if` block evaluates `track.permalink.url` (which is always `undefined`), so this condition:

```
opts.startUrl == track.permalink.url
```

Always evaluates to `false`

**Update:** as @brianpeiris points out, the correct fix here would be to change the condition to:

```
opts.startUrl == track.permalink_url
```

Comment: In other words, it's just a typo! Change `track.permalink.url` to `track.permalink_url` (Note the underscore).

Comment: OMFG! I feel so stupid now. :P This would have taken me ages to see. Thanks!

Comment: @PeeHaa: No problem, sometimes all you need is another set of eyes :)

Comment: @brianpeiris: Good point, I will update my answer to make the fix clear.

Answer (score 0):

Start printing both the values and see what is the difference , otherwise do this

```
if (opts.startUrl.toLowerCase() == track.permalink.url.toLowerCase())
```